# How to sort arraylist by mutiple level fields in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

```
Class Activity{
    private int level;
    private Activity predecessor;
}
```

My program creates instances of `Activity`, puts them in an Arraylist and sorts them by two fields `level` and `predecessor`. predecessor is first compared.

For instance,  if `predecessor` is not `null`, the predecessor `Activity` of the current activity should be first and it will be second. After satisfying the `predecessor` condition the following could be ordered by `level`.

```
List<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<Activity>();
//Add some activities.
activities.add(Activity);
activities.add(Activity);
Collections.sort(activities,getActivityComparator());

private Comparator<Activity> getActivityComparator() {
    return new Comparator<Activity>() { 
        public int compare(Activity act1, Activity act2) {                
            if (act1 == null) {
                if (act2 == null) {
                    return 0; // Both activities are null
                } else {
                    return -1; // act1 is NULL, so put act1 in the end of
                    // the sorted list
                }
            } else {
                if (act2 == null) {
                    return 1; 
                }
            }

         Activity preAct2 = act2.getPredecessor();
         if(preAct2!=null&&preAct2==act1)
             return -1;

          //Adding this by Joeri Hendrickx's suggestion
         Activity preAct1 = act1.getPredecessor();
         if(preAct1!=null&&preAct1==act2)
             return 1;

         return act2.getLevel()-act1.getLevel(); 
        }
    };
}
```

I have written the above code and tested a lot, but it outputted inconstant ordering if I putted different ordering into Arrarylist. so definitely this is incorrect method to implement this. Seems the root cause is not every two elements were compared. says Activity act1>Activity act2(by level condition), Activity act2>Activity act3(by level condition), it doesn't mean Activity act1>Activity act3(by predecessor condition).

Here I came up with an new idea that is to use bubble sort instead of using interface sort of Collections. it will compare every two elements that don't need comparator transitive any more. how do you think?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your comparator is not describing a correct symmetric and transitive relation.

Consider the following three objects:

```
act1{predecessor:null, level:1}    
act2{predecessor:act1, level:1}    
act3{predecessor:null, level:0}
act4{predecessor:act2, level:2}
```

Now, where comp is your comparator, `comp(act1, act2)` will return -1, but `comp(act2, act1)` will return 0.  This is not **symmetric**.

`comp(act1, act2)` will return -1, `comp(act2, act4)` will return -1, but `comp(act1, act4)` will return 1.  This is not **transitive**.

A comparator must describe a correct **reflexive**, **symmetric** and **transitive** relation in order for it to work.

Edited after seeing Axtaxt's post: the problem you describe here cannot be accomplished with a normal sort, because it's always possible to construct a scenario where, by these rules, you get a loop in your sort hierarchy.  So it's not possible to make a transitive comparator *with only this data*.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: @JammyC.c I added an explanation on how to accomplish it.  For a comparator this complex, I also suggest a unit test.

Comment: Thanks, has added the code to implement the predecessor relation in both directions. for making transitive, what your way is that to write chain comparison, put level compare first. then is predecessor compare?

Comment: @Jammy C.c actually, Axtavt is correct, even with these changes you can still construct an example that will not work.  He's right that this cannot be accomplished with a normal sort.

Comment: Thanks, your idea make sense. but I have idea here that is to use bubble sort. it will compare every two elements that don't need comparator transitive any more. how do you think?

Comment: @JammyC.c No, bubble sort also relies on the transitive relationship.  If the relation is not a complete ordering of your set, none of the standard sorting algorithms will perform correctly.  In the case of bubble sort, you could even construct a set where it will keep running indefinately.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you cannot make your comparator transitive at all due to possibility of the following loop (thick line - predcessor, thin line - greater than):

[image]

So, you have a partial order and general purpose sorting algorithms are not applicable here.

If you need order by level only among successors of the same activity, you can achieve it using the following simple algorithm:

- Build a multimap from `Activity` to its direct successors
- Build a tree with the following properties:

  - Each node contains an activity, root node has `null` activity
  - Subnodes of each node correspond to direct successors of its activity, ordered by levels

  It can be created using the following algorithm:

  - Create a root node with `null` activity
  - For each node extract the corresponding successors from the multimap and create subnodes for them, apply it recursively
- Traverse that tree

Comment: Thanks, your idea make sense.  but I have idea here that is to use bubble sort. it will compare every two elements that don't need comparator transitive any more. how do you think?

Comment: @JammyC.c: Bubble sort relies on transitivity as well, so it won't help.

Answer (score 0):

The compare method of comparator is defined as:
"Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second."

Which means if you want act1 to be in the end when its null, you have to return a positive integer -> act1 is greater -> act1 will be at the end.
You have your positive and negative integers mixed.

```
if (act1 == null) {
            if (act2 == null) {
                return 0; // Both activities are null
            } else {
                return 1; // act1 is NULL, so put act1 in the end of
                // the sorted list
            }
        } else {
            if (act2 == null) {
                return -1; 
            }
        }
```

Also, for the same reason you would need to use

```
return act1.getLevel()-act2.getLevel();
```

imaging a comparator for integers that receives 2 and 3.
You would want it to return a negative int because the first argument is less than the second. -> arg1-arg2 = -1
instead of arg2-arg1 like you did...

Comment: This is correct, but I don't think it will fix the inconsistent ordering.

Comment: You're right. It won't fix the problem that @Joeri Hendrickx is describing.. But still important :)